# is there any way to update python 3.6 in linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am using using python 3.6 in 2020 i updated my python to 3.7 but the idle remain same as 3.6.
i want to use pip module such as wolfram alpha .
 I tried it on 3.6 but it need the newest version of python.
**how to resolve this**

Comment: Try the command **idle3.7**

Comment: Yes, of course, you can install any version of Python on linux. It seems your problem is you cannot find the corresponding IDLE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Linux :**

This is the bash command to update python to the newest version.

`pkg update python`